# Why cant I add Add ReplyUrl to AAD Application using Service Principle and Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, command-line-interface, service-principal

I need to add a ReplyUrl to an AAD application using a Service Principal using Azure CLI, but I am getting an error "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation".  I originally tried this from Azure DevOps, but have now reproduced it from just CLI.

I started using DevOps and a service principal created when I connected the Target AAD tenant to my DevOps organisation.  I have granted API permissions Microsoft.Graph.Application.ReadWrite.All to the service principal and granted admin consent.  I have generated a new ClientSecret and used that to logon to the tenant using the CLI.  When I run the command to update the reply urls, that's when I get the insufficient privileges error described above.

If I run the CLI command from Cloud Shell bash it works fine.

```
az login --service-principal -u xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxxxxx --tenant xxxxxxxxxx 

[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Ultimate",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "user": {
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
```

then

```
az ad app update --id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --reply-urls https://localhost:44381/ 

Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

If I run the az ad app update command from cloud shell it works fine.
If I try to use the service principal created by DevOps then I get the error.

I just created a clean new principal outside of DevOps (az ad app create-for-rbac) and then manually added the Application.ReadWrite.All permission and consented to that - and that gives me the same error too!

[Application API Permissions and Consent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLxl9.png)

I have looked at the similar questions - but the closest one had an answer where we need to give the right permissions and grant consent as the answer - which I have already done.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have granted the wrong permissions. Azure CLI uses AAD Graph endpoint, so you need to grant [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart) permissions to the service principal, not [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) permission.

What you need is Application.ReadWrite.All permission(**Azure AD Graph**).

[image]

**Note**: Browser caching in the portal made it appear as if the reply urls were not updated. Just open the portal again, you will see the update.